# How can I organise kivy layout?

Tags: python, layout, kivy

I'm new to python and want to have a UI for my small app. I use kivy as the GUI framework. I'm wondering about the layout.

[image]

How can I organise my layout? I have tried embedding boxlayout inside gridlayout, but alway got messed in position.

Comment: can you provide more details, or better yet some code you've written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just embed `GridLayout` inside vertically oriented `BoxLayout` and use `size_hint` to select how much space should widgets take. For example `size_hint: 1, 0.25` results with widget taking all available space horizontally and 1/4 of the available space vertically. Result:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        size_hint: 1, 0.25
        text: 'Label1'
    GridLayout:
        size_hint: 1, 0.25
        cols: 2
        Button
            text: 'Button1'
        Button
            text: 'Button2'
        Button
            text: 'Button3'
        Button
            text: 'Button4'
    Label:
        size_hint: 1, 0.5
        text: 'Label2'
''')

class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```